# Splash screen in metro apps

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi i'm working on windows 8 javascript html5 apps i'm trying to implement splash screen using java script in metro apps .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=timeout;
function timeout(){

window.setTimeout("redirect()",3000)

}

function redirect(){
window.location="expand.html"
return
}
</script>
```

this is html code i try this one its working good can u explain me how to implement in java script metro apps,using this  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every Windows 8 Store app must start with a [splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465346.aspx) already, and you just have to provide the image for it; Win RT takes care of the rest.

You can [create an 'extended' splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700390.aspx), but that's in cases where you have a lengthy initialization sequence, and the recommended design pattern there is to use the same image as the built-in screen with a progress ring indicator.